# Do we really need a [ramanujan-radicals] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are currently three questions tagged as [ramanujan-radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ramanujan-radicals). One is a duplicate of another, and a third one.

Is this tag really necessary?

Comment: Move that we change it to "ramanujanicals"?

Comment: Alexnader, perhaps "ramicals" or "ramicalujans"?

Comment: The reputation needed to create tags is [just 300](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). To prevent proliferation of tags, it really should be raised to 1000.

Comment: No. That tag is not necessary.

Answer (score 23):

IMO this tag is unnecessary, [nested-radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nested-radicals) describes these questions well enough.

Comment: ...or maybe even just '[tag:sequences-and-series]'

Comment: I have asked whether ([tag:nested-radicals]) should be a synonym of ([tag:sequences-and-series]) in [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11751/nested-radicals-tag).

Comment: While we are on the topic of unnecessary things, is this conversation necessary? I think we are applying a supraoptimal amount of energy on optimization.